# Create partitions for new install of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, raid, raid-1

Does it really make sense anymore to create partitions?

I'm installing Windows 7 x64 and would like to have the simplicity of 1 large partition.  If it matters, the main hard drive is 2x120GB SSD RAID.  And I have an extra 128GB SSD drive too in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it really make sense anymore to create partitions?

Yes. If anything, now it makes more sense (drives are larger).

Separation of OS, data, and programs means that you can format your OS drive without losing data. In my experience also makes things easier when adding new drives; you can move a whole partition to a new drive without the need to update shortcuts/paths information.

See also this list of [benefits of multiple partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Benefits_of_multiple_partitions).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make a partition, don't.

If you have files saved on your current partition, and don't want those touched... then it would make sense... (You may want to backup just in case.)

Comment: You may also want a recovery partition (today's standard).  But if you just want simplicity, just want one partition... ...